# OpenMP program gets a random SIGSEGV when spawned by Java Runtime.exec - solution posted below

Tags: java, runtime, segmentation-fault

In java:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec( command, null, workingDir)
```

runs my C++ program but the program randomly gets a SIGSEGV about 10% of the time.

If I use the following code, everything works flawlessly:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec( command, new String[]{"PATH=/tmp"}, workingDir);
```

strange but true.

Comment: And your questions is what? Or did you mistakenly include the answer in the question as well?

Comment: The form of the question and answer doesn’t really provide any insight into why things happen. There are myriads of reasons why *your* program fails and this solution may work for *you*, but there’s no understanding *why* so others can’t get much help from it. I would suggest debugging the actual reason, including the code that causes it etc if this is to be helpful.

Comment: We could not discover the cause of the SIGSEGV - it happened at seemingly random locations in the program and only about 5-10% of the time - on exactly the same input parameters.  It was indeed mysterious.  I'm mainly posting the solution that seemed to make our problem "go away".  Perhaps others will find it helpful if they run into similar difficulties.

Comment: Are you asking how to avoid getting a SIGSEGV about 10% of the time, or are you asking *why* your second line of code fixes the SIGSEGV problem?

Comment: I added a comment below describing how I got rid of the SIGSEGV.... I still don't know why my "fix" works... but I wanted to leave something for the next poor guy who suffers through this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It appears as if the problem lies in openMP.  The C++ code in question uses openMP and when it is used in a mode that DOES NOT require multiple processors, you have to call it via:

Runtime.getRuntime().exec( cmd, new String[]{}, workingDir);

If you call it with:

Runtime.getRuntime().exec( cmd, new String[] {"GOMP_CPU_AFFINITY=0-7"}, workingDir)

Then you get the spurious/random SIGSEGV errors.

I'm going to claim that this has something more to do with OpenMP than necessarily with Java's Runtime.exec().

Answer (score -1):

If I use the following code, everything works flawlessly:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec( command, new String[]{"PATH=/tmp"}, workingDir);
```

It may sound strange but it works!

Comment: Why was this "down-marked"... I gave the solution to the problem posed above.    I thought this is what "stackoverflow" was all about.